# SwiftUI Map Can't Use Buttons on Annotation View on Tap, iOS17, Xcode 15

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, mapkit

Now that MapKit can add polylines in iOS 17 and Xcode 15 I'm trying to create an app that allows the user to set an Annotation on a map and then once set, allow the user to interact with that Annotation on tapping. I want to be able to change the annotation content to a new view with additional buttons. I can setup the map with annotations and respond to taps on an annotation, including changing the Annotation View, but taps on the buttons on the editing Annotation View do not work. The tap drops through to the map and dismisses the editing Annotation.

This simplified code (without the polylines) can be run as is:

import SwiftUI
import MapKit

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    @State private var waypointSelection: Waypoint?

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack{
            Text("This Trip")
            Text("Waypoint Count: \(Waypoint.waypoints.count)")
           // ZStack {
                Map(position: $cameraPosition, selection: $waypointSelection) {
                    ForEach(Waypoint.waypoints, id: \.self) { wp in
                        Annotation("Waypoint", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: wp.latitude, longitude: wp.longitude)) {
                            if (waypointSelection != nil && waypointSelection?.sequence == wp.sequence) {
                            
                                MyAnnotationEditView(wp: wp)
                            
                            } else {
                                MyAnnotationShowView(wp: wp)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        print(wp.sequence)
                                        if let index = Waypoint.waypoints.firstIndex(of: wp) {
                                            print("\(Waypoint.waypoints[index].sequence)")
                                        }
                                        waypointSelection = wp
                                    }//tap
                            }//if else
                        }//annotation
                    }//for each
                    .annotationTitles(.hidden)
                }//map
            //}//z
        }//v stack
        .onChange(of: waypointSelection) { oldValue, newValue in
            print("waypointSelection changed")
        }//on change
    }//body
}//struct


struct Waypoint: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var sequence: Int

    init(name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, sequence: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.sequence = sequence
    }

    static let waypoints = [
        Waypoint(name: "San Jose", latitude: 37.338207, longitude: -121.886330, sequence: 0),
        Waypoint(name: "Fremont", latitude: 37.548271, longitude: -121.988571, sequence: 1),
        Waypoint(name: "Vallejo", latitude: 38.1041, longitude: -122.2566, sequence: 2)
    ]

}//waypoint


struct MyAnnotationEditView: View {

    var wp: Waypoint

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .frame(width: 120, height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Button {
                    print("you tapped trash")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.title2)
                }
                Text("\(wp.sequence)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title2)
                Button {
                    print("you tapped add")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.title2)
                }
            }//h
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }//z
    }//body
}//struct

struct MyAnnotationShowView: View {

    var wp: Waypoint

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .backgroundStyle(.blue).opacity(0.4)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            Text("\(wp.sequence)")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 15 beta 4, iOS 17

Comment: I have an app that uses UIKit MapKit. Thought about what I had to do to support VisionPro. Which needs much more space for Buttons. I then looked at Apples Maps app and they don't use callouts any more. They use a sheet on iPhones and something like a sidebar on iPads. VisionPro might be the reason why they don't support callouts in SwiftUI Maps any more. To discourage us from doing things that won't work well on VisionOS. (centering callouts on the map is missing too, should you solve your problem).